Distance between many points in two dataframes within 50m of one another
I have two dataframes of distance data (this is made up data to use as an example):
ed <- data.frame(Site=c(1,1,2,2),
              session=c(1,2,1,2),
              Lat=c(34.18985, 34.19263, 33.80374, 33.80405),
              Long=c(-117.17417,-117.16799, -116.73119, -116.73084))

od <- data.frame(Site=c(3,3,4,4,3,3,3,4),
              species=c('koala', 'hedgehog', 'koala', 'hedgehog','koala', 'hedgehog', 'koala', 'hedgehog'),
              count=c(3,50,20,9,4,5,6,7),
              session=c(1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2),
              Lat=c(34.189, 34.1925, 33.80380, 33.80410,34.189, 34.1925, 33.80380, 33.80410),
              Long=c(-117,1743,-117.16799, -116.73119, -116.731,-117.1743,-117.16799, -116.73119, -116.731))

Unfortunately, the data was collected using two methods at two different survey scales. I am trying to match them up into a new dataframe. I need to sum all the counts from 'od' within each session and species that are within 50m of a location in 'ed'. That way I can have a dataframe for all of the 'ed' data that includes a column for 'Total count' for each of the two species (see below as an example of the dataframe I hope to end up with)
ed2 <- data.frame(Site=c(1,1,2,2),
          session=c(1,2,1,2),
          Lat=c(34.18985, 34.19263, 33.80374, 33.80405),
          Long=c(-117.17417,-117.16799, -116.73119, -116.73084),
          TotalKo = (ww,xx,yy,zz), # filled in from analysis
          TotalHe = (aa,bb,cc,dd))# filled in from analysis

Thank you for your help

You could make use of the sf package to work with the data as spatial objects. First, you need to use st_buffer to create a 50 m buffer and st_intersection to get which points in od fall inside the latter buffer. Then, you can drop the geometry (st_drop_geometry) and summarise by groups. Finally, you need to use pivot_wider to set the results in the desired wide format.
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Convert to sf objects
ed <- st_as_sf(ed, 
         coords = c("Long", "Lat"),
         # WGS 84
         crs = 4326,
         # Do not remove columns of long lat
         remove = FALSE)

od <- st_as_sf(od, 
               coords = c("Long", "Lat"),
               crs = 4326)

# Buffer
ed <- ed |>
  # 50 m buffer
  st_buffer(dist = 50)

resul <- ed |>
  # Intersect ed and od
  st_intersection(od)

resul |>
  # Drop geometry
  st_drop_geometry() |>
  # Group by site, session and species, add Lat and Long so they are not dropped
  group_by(Site, session, Lat, Long, species) |>
  # Sum the number of count
  summarise(sum = sum(count),
            .groups = "drop") |>
  # Get in wide format
  pivot_wider(names_from = "species",
              values_from = "sum",
              values_fill = 0)

# A tibble: 3 × 6
#   Site session   Lat  Long hedgehog koala
#  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1       2  34.2 -117.       55     0
#2     2       1  33.8 -117.       16    26
#3     2       2  33.8 -117.       16    26


Thankyou very much, that worked perfectly.

With sf objects you could also use spatial join with st_is_within_distance() binary predicate:
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.12.1, GDAL 3.8.4, PROJ 9.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

(ed_sf <- tibble(ed) |> st_as_sf(coords = c("Long", "Lat"), crs = "WGS84", remove = FALSE))
#> Simple feature collection with 4 features and 4 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -117.1742 ymin: 33.80374 xmax: -116.7308 ymax: 34.19263
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>    Site session   Lat  Long             geometry
#> * <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>          <POINT [°]>
#> 1     1       1  34.2 -117. (-117.1742 34.18985)
#> 2     1       2  34.2 -117.  (-117.168 34.19263)
#> 3     2       1  33.8 -117. (-116.7312 33.80374)
#> 4     2       2  33.8 -117. (-116.7308 33.80405)

(od_sf <- tibble(od) |> st_as_sf(coords = c("Long", "Lat"), crs = "WGS84"))
#> Simple feature collection with 8 features and 4 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -117.1743 ymin: 33.8038 xmax: -116.731 ymax: 34.1925
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 8 × 5
#>    Site species  count session            geometry
#> * <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>         <POINT [°]>
#> 1     3 koala        3       1  (-117.1743 34.189)
#> 2     3 hedgehog    50       2  (-117.168 34.1925)
#> 3     4 koala       20       1 (-116.7312 33.8038)
#> 4     4 hedgehog     9       2  (-116.731 33.8041)
#> 5     3 koala        4       1  (-117.1743 34.189)
#> 6     3 hedgehog     5       1  (-117.168 34.1925)
#> 7     3 koala        6       2 (-116.7312 33.8038)
#> 8     4 hedgehog     7       2  (-116.731 33.8041)

# spatial join, inner, using st_is_within_distance(..., 50)
st_join(od_sf, ed_sf, join = st_is_within_distance, 50, suffix = c(".od", ".ed"), left = FALSE)
#> Simple feature collection with 10 features and 8 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -117.168 ymin: 33.8038 xmax: -116.731 ymax: 34.1925
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 10 × 9
#>    Site.od species count session.od            geometry Site.ed session.ed
#>  *   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>      <dbl>         <POINT [°]>   <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1       3 hedgeh…    50          2  (-117.168 34.1925)       1          2
#>  2       4 koala      20          1 (-116.7312 33.8038)       2          1
#>  3       4 koala      20          1 (-116.7312 33.8038)       2          2
#>  4       4 hedgeh…     9          2  (-116.731 33.8041)       2          1
#>  5       4 hedgeh…     9          2  (-116.731 33.8041)       2          2
#>  6       3 hedgeh…     5          1  (-117.168 34.1925)       1          2
#>  7       3 koala       6          2 (-116.7312 33.8038)       2          1
#>  8       3 koala       6          2 (-116.7312 33.8038)       2          2
#>  9       4 hedgeh…     7          2  (-116.731 33.8041)       2          1
#> 10       4 hedgeh…     7          2  (-116.731 33.8041)       2          2
#> # ℹ 2 more variables: Lat <dbl>, Long <dbl>

If 10 records is not quite what you expected after frames are joined, then not all od records in provided example have a match in ed; and some other od records are within 50 m range of multiple ed sites. If there's a chance that you have similar cases in your actual data set, you might want to take extra care to make sure sightings are counted only once / for one ed.
You can check this with a distance matrix and by counting number of < 50m distances in each row:
# distance matrix
st_distance(od_sf, ed_sf)
#> Units: [m]
#>             [,1]        [,2]         [,3]        [,4]
#> [1,]    95.26919   706.93790 59193.505165 59190.79270
#> [2,]   640.25546    14.45536 59077.180149 59073.91807
#> [3,] 59248.69772 59082.84514     6.671706    42.64485
#> [4,] 59236.56273 59070.33356    43.710572    15.79441
#> [5,]    95.26919   706.93790 59193.505165 59190.79270
#> [6,]   640.25546    14.45536 59077.180149 59073.91807
#> [7,] 59248.69772 59082.84514     6.671706    42.64485
#> [8,] 59236.56273 59070.33356    43.710572    15.79441

# minimum distances from each od to closest ed
st_distance(od_sf, ed_sf) |> apply(1, min)
#> [1] 95.269193 14.455363  6.671706 15.794409 95.269193 14.455363  6.671706
#> [8] 15.794409

# number of ed records within 50m for each od record
(st_distance(od_sf, ed_sf) < units::set_units(50, m)) |> rowSums()
#> [1] 0 1 2 2 0 1 2 2

Created on 2024-08-02 with reprex v2.1.0
